# Trigger in SQL that updates the same atribute but in two different rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, database-trigger

I'm trying to solve the following trouble:

I have two tables, The first one is called 'Payments' and looks like this:

```
id_payment |  date      | id_month |  total 
-----------+------------+----------+--------
1          | 2019-01-01 |    1     |     0 
2          | 2019-01-02 |    2     |   160
```

The second table is called 'Month' and looks like this:

```
id_month | month_name    | initial_date | final_date | total_payments 
---------+---------------+--------------+------------+---------------
    1    | January/2019  | 2019-01-01   | 2019-31-01 |      0
    2    | February/2019 | 2019-01-02   | 2019-28-02 |    160
```

Now the issue is that if I update the date of one of the payments, the trigger should make the tables look like this:

```
id_payment | date       | id_month |  total 
-----------+------------+----------+--------
    1      | 2019-01-01 |    1     |    0 
    2      | 2019-01-01 |    1     |  160


id_month | month_name    | initial_date | final_date | total_payments 
---------+---------------+--------------+------------+---------------
   1     | January/2019  | 2019-01-01   | 2019-31-01 |   160
   2     | February/2019 | 2019-01-02   | 2019-28-02 |     0
```

But the final result is like this:

```
id_payment |  date      | id_month |  total 
-----------+------------+----------+-------
    1      | 2019-01-01 |   1      |    0 
    2      | 2019-01-01 |   1      |  160


id_month | month_name    | initial_date | final_date | total_payments 
---------+---------------+--------------+------------+---------------
    1    | January/2019  | 2019-01-01   | 2019-31-01 |    160
    2    | February/2019 | 2019-01-02   | 2019-28-02 |    160
```

My trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdatingTotalInPaymentsInTheMonth 
ON Payments
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE  
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @id_month AS INT

    SELECT @id_month = id_month FROM inserted
    SET @id_month = @id_month

    DECLARE @total_payments AS MONEY

    SELECT @total_paymdents = SUM(p.total) 
    FROM Payments AS p 
    WHERE o.id_month = @id_month  

    SET @total_payments = @total_payments

    UPDATE month  
    SET total_payments = @total_payments
    FROM month AS m  
    INNER JOIN inserted as i ON i.id_month = m.id_month  
END
```

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the syntax used

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things in your query that don't match your tables, like id_mes for example, and o vs p alias in your payments query, but the real problem is that your trigger assumes a single row.

This not the case, the trigger will be called once for the whole update, and will have multiple rows in inserted.

This is an update that will work, depending on the database. You should be able to adapt it if your database doesnt support CTEs

```
;with totals as (
    select id_month, sum(total) as total_payments 
    from payments
    where id_month in (select id_month FROM inserted)
    group by id_month
)
update month set total_payments=t.total_payments
from month 
join totals on totals.id_month=month.id_month
```